# UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout different start position for a group

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uikit, uicollectionviewlayout

I am trying to achieve the following:

[image]

As you see in the picture, The first row starts with no margin on the left, and the second row begins with a margin.

**I've tried to create two groups for each row.** and wanted to give them different intents for the leading edge. (0 for the first group and 100 for the second group.) But there is no method like that. The `contentInset` method applies to every item's spacing.

**This is what I've tried:**

```
lazy var compositionalLayout: UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout = {
    
    let config = UICollectionViewCompositionalLayoutConfiguration()
    config.scrollDirection = .horizontal

    let itemSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1), heightDimension: .absolute(48))
    let item = NSCollectionLayoutItem(layoutSize: itemSize)
    item.contentInsets = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: 5, leading: 5, bottom: 0, trailing: 0)
    
    
    let groupSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1), heightDimension: .absolute(48))
    let group = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.horizontal(layoutSize: groupSize, subitems: [item])
    
    let group2 = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.horizontal(layoutSize: groupSize, subitems: [item])
    
    let nestedGroupSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(0.7), heightDimension: .absolute(48*2))
    let nestedGroup = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.vertical(layoutSize: nestedGroupSize, subitems: [group, group2])
    
    let sect = NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: nestedGroup)
    
    return UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout(section: sect, configuration: config)
}()
```

**The result:**

[image]

**There should be a margin at the beginning of the second row. How can I do that?**

Comment: have you tried `group.contentInsets`?

Comment: Yeah, it just sets the spacing between the items. Same effect with the item.contentInsets